# Why does my collection view layout place the cells on the edge of the screen when there is enough room for 2 cells to be side by side?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFvc.jpg)

[How it looks on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dywrm.png)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Do you have a `UICollectionView` to the edge of your storyboard view controller. and you do have storyboard view controller size for only the iphone size set up? Are you using constraints?

Comment: That's just what the flow layout does.  If you say what your desired behavior is someone might be able to help you achieve it.